# Azure durable functions: Get Execution time

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I am building an azure durable function which has may activities/azure functions to be called as a part of Job execution.

I have a requirement to view the total execution time taken for completing an orchestration instance. Is there any way to read the total execution time took to run an instance of durable function orchestration?

Comment: If you have configured Application Insights it will show you those results, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#view-telemetry-in-monitor-tab

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks, Yeah this option is possible only when insights are enabled.  I am looking for some kind of API using which I can query orchestration steps on  instance id?. Any known api's ?

Comment: wel, application insights does store this as well so you can create queries to do this. Maybe you can use [GetStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#query-instances) as well.

Comment: Yeah this helps!. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the total execution time for an orchestration by calling the statusQueryGetUri returned when the durable function is first created. The call URI should look like this:

```
http://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/<instanceId>?taskHub=<taskHub>&connection=<connectionName>&code=<systemKey>&showHistory=true
```

The response should look like this:

```
{
  "createdTime": "2018-02-28T05:18:49Z",
  "historyEvents": [
      ...
  ],
  "input": null,
  "customStatus": { "nextActions": ["A", "B", "C"], "foo": 2 },
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2018-02-28T05:18:54Z",
  "output": [
      ...
  ],
  "runtimeStatus": "Completed"
}
```

The duration can be determined by polling the status URI until the **runtimeStatus** reaches any of the terminal states (Failed, Cancelled, Terminated, or Completed), and then subtracting **createdTime** from **lastUpdatedTime**.

The following Typescript snippet shows how a the above JSON response (parsed into the status variable) could be processed to show duration as hh:mm:ss:

```
  formatDuration(status: DurableFunctionJob): string {
    const diff:number = (new Date(status.lastUpdatedTime).getTime() 
                         - new Date(status.createdTime).getTime());
    return new Date(diff).toISOString().substr(11,8);
  }
```

For the example response, this function outputs **00:00:05**.